# How to remove item listbox & dictionary on click?

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, listbox

I created a listbox with dictionary.

But I want to remove item listbox & dictionary at once on click.

[image: This is my listbox]

Code:

Xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxPlayList" SelectionMode="Extended"/>

<Button x:Name="addbtn" Margin="2,5,41,5" Click="addbtn_Click" />

<Button x:Name="removebtn" Click="removebtn_Click" />
```

Xaml.cs:

```
public  Dictionary<string, string> fileDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

private void addbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var listCount = ListBoxPlayList.Items.Count;
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog ofd = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.DefaultExt = ".mp3";
            ofd.Filter = "All|*.*";
            ofd.Multiselect = true;
            Nullable<bool> result = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (result == true)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ofd.FileNames.Length; i++)
                {
                    var filePath = ofd.FileNames[i];
                    var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                    fileDictionary.Add(fileName, filePath);
                    ListBoxPlayList.Items.Add(fileName);
                }
                ListBoxPlayList.SelectedIndex = listCount;
            }
        }
```

**I am trying by this code:**

But item remove from Dictionary but not remove from listbox when I click the remove button.

```
   private void remove(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var itemsToRemove = listbox4.SelectedItems;
            foreach (var item in itemsToRemove)
            {
                fileDictionary.Remove(item.ToString());
                listbox4.Items.Remove(item);
            }

        }
```

**Note:**

I want to remove item from listbox & fileDictionary at once.

& Without the playing item.

This code worked when I don't use dictionary.

```
private void removebtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
     object[] itemsToRemove = new object[ListBoxPlayList.SelectedItems.Count];
                ListBoxPlayList.SelectedItems.CopyTo(itemsToRemove, 0);

                foreach (object item in itemsToRemove)
                {
   if (mediaelement.Source != new Uri(item.ToString()))  //MediaPlayer source
   ListBoxPlayList.Items.Remove(item);

}
```

}

**Question:**

How can I remove selected items from listbox & dictionary on click and ignore remove item which is playing on my mediaelement??

Comment: ObservableCollection along an MVVM ?

Comment: What do you mean??

Comment: Proper way to do this, a model your form would work against, with commands for adding/removing, finally an observable collection does notify subscribers to changes in it. Here's an example : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Easy-MVVM-Examples-fb8c409f

Comment: I am not worked anytime with MVVM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Always use parenthesis until you are familiar with the basics. Read my comments below.

```
private void removebtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     object[] itemsToRemove = new object[ListBoxPlayList.SelectedItems.Count];
     ListBoxPlayList.SelectedItems.CopyTo(itemsToRemove, 0);

     foreach (object item in itemsToRemove)
     {
         string filePath;
         fileDictionary.TryGetValue(item.ToString(), out filePath);
         if (mediaelement.Source != new Uri(filePath))  //MediaPlayer source
         {  //you forgot the parenthesis for the if condition.
            ListBoxPlayList.Items.Remove(item);//remove from list
            fileDictionary.Remove(item.ToString());//remove from dictionary
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Missing ToString(). Haven't tested the code. But that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please check with this code? Without getting the entire code, I cant test it.

```
private void removebtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    object[] itemsToRemove = new object[ListBoxPlayList.SelectedItems.Count];
    ListBoxPlayList.SelectedItems.CopyTo(itemsToRemove, 0);
    foreach (var item in itemsToRemove)
    {
        fileDictionary.Remove(item.ToString());
        ListBoxPlayList.Items.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: How possible same code here?

`fileDictionary.Remove(item.ToString());
fileDictionary.Remove(item.ToString());`

Comment: it's remove item from dictionary but ignore listbox item

Comment: I think for removing the selected items, you may need to use `ListBoxPlayList.Remove(item);`

Comment: Its working normally without dictionary based listbox.

Comment: But you need to update the value in `Dictionary` too. Did you try using an `ObservableCollection` as mentioned in one of the comments?

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please check if this works. You can get ObservableCollection examples from the internet.

Comment: `listbox4.Remove(item);` its error
I think it will be
`listbox4.Items.Remove(item);`

Comment: No
Your code is error

I tried this code but error when i click remove button

https://i.imgur.com/xpZtyYG.jpg

Comment: Please include the entire code in question. I cant see the image since it is blocked here.

Comment: `private void remove(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          
            var itemsToRemove = listbox4.SelectedItems;
            foreach (var item in itemsToRemove)
            {
                fileDictionary.Remove(item.ToString());
                listbox4.Items.Remove(item);
            }

        }`

when I click remove button it error shown 
`foreach (var item in itemsToRemove)` this statement (in)

Comment: Maybe you did not select any list item?

Comment: No way

1st I select item then click button

Comment: I use this code for select all to remove.

`if (e.Key == Key.A && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
            {

                ListBoxPlayList.SelectAll();
               
                
            }`
It's select all but not remove

Comment: Hey Its remove only one file , Multiple selected item not remove.
How can?

Comment: @TaniaAkter : When I tested it, it is able to delete all selected items.

Comment: Yes
But when I click control +a and select all by this code: 
` ListBoxPlayList.SelectAll(); `
Then all select but not delete

Comment: That you need to debug and check the `ListBoxPlayList.SelectedItems`

Comment: `if (e.Key == Key.A && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control) { ListBoxPlayList.SelectAll(); }`

It is not working for all select

Comment: `private void listView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}`

Comment: No 
My code is right for me.

  `private void listbox4_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Key == Key.A && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
            {

                listbox4.SelectAll();
            }

          
        }`
It's select all but not remove

Comment: Replace that condition with `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)`